# How to use google.visualization.ArrowFormat for individual cells?

Tags: google-visualization, visualization, data-visualization

I'm trying to specify a different `base` (option from [Google Charts API Summary](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#arrowformat)) for each cell in a table column. However, I have only been able to specify a base for a whole column (not for individual cells).

Here's an [example of full column base specification](https://jsfiddle.net/g5q1n3wb/1/).

[image]

I would like to compare each cell to a different value and use that to decide the type of arrow. Is this possible? I understand that `formatter.format()` can be applied to whole columns only, but is there a way to specify an array, for example, that contains the values that should be used to compare each cell in the column?

Finally, after applying the format, how can I make all numbers be aligned to the right again? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bit late I suppose but possible, although no beauty. :-)

After format of the table, set the cells `className` to the up/down as you want:

up:
`dataTable.setProperty(row, col, 'className', "google-visualization-formatters-arrow-ug")`

down:
`dataTable.setProperty(row, col, 'className', "google-visualization-formatters-arrow-dr")`